# How to create MS Access data entry form with rolling 12 months for each row

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm creating a data entry form in Access where sales people can select a product, then enter a quantity for that product in each of 12 columns representing the next twelve months. For a given project, there may be up to ten products, so each product will be on a separate row.

**Tables:** 
**Project** - fields ProjectID, ProjectName, City, SalespersonID, StartDate
**ProjectDetail** - fields ProjectDetailID, ProjectID, ProductID, Date, Quantity
**Product** - fields ProductID, ProductName
**Salesman** - fields SalespersonID, SalespersonName

Currently I have the Project form with the simple project header information, and I want the ProjectDetail information to be a subform, of course. But - when I used a query to give me "buckets" of Quantity for Month0 (the current month), Month1, Month2, etc., I found that I can't enter data into the form because the fields are based on an expression.

What's the best way to handle this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add more details to understand your requirement.

Comment: I'm hoping my each of my subform's rows will look like this: Product, Month0Quantity, Month1Quantity, Month2Quantity, etc.  I'm not worried about the labels for the month names but what I want is for the salesman to select a product then enter 12 quantities for that product - one quantity for each of the next 12 months. Then the next row is the next product and its 12 months of quantities to be produced.        Does that make sense? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each `ProjectDetail` entry will have multiple sets of `Date` and `Quantity`, it might be wise to pull those out into a separate table with a one-to-many relationship to `ProjectDetailID`, especially if you anticipate the number of date/quantity pairs could change from twelve.  So, a `ProjectDetailQuantity` table would have fields `ProjectDetailQuantityID`, `ProjectDetailID`, `Date`, `Quantity`.  On your form, you would have the `Project` main form, with a sub form to `ProjectDetail` and another subform to `ProjectDetailQuantity`.

Comment: .Thank you! That was the missing piece.